# What are some good analogies about electrical power?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, power

What are some good analogies about electrical power? I understand the mathematical part of $P=VI$, but I would like to somehow visualize it in a practical electric circuit.

Comment: $V$ can be thought as the amount of work (energy) that you have to apply to bring a charge from point $A$ to point $B$. $I$ is the current, hence, the charges that cross from $A$ to $B$ per unit time. Therefore $P$ is simply the amount of energy per unit time that you give the system to bring all those charges (per unit time) from point $A$ to point $B$.

Comment: You may also compare it to water flow to see if it helps you understand.

Comment: $Power$ is, I think, an intrinsically abstract idea – as is $energy$, on which the concept of power is based. Therefore I'd go along with PML, even if it's not as visual as you'd like. Of course you should imagine particular cases, such as rate of transfer of electrical work to random energy in a resistor, or of electrical work partly to mechanical work in an electric motor.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Very powerful analogy if you're familiar with fluid flows.  If you're familiar with heat transfer, that can also be a good analog.

Comment: [Hydraulics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy).

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question which is generally regarded as *off-topic* because it's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Well potential difference ($V$) is defined as the energy transferred in an electrical circuit per coulomb of charge that passes through the circuit.

Current ($I$) is defined as the rate of flow of charge, so the amount of charge that passes through a given component per second.

Therefore, $IV$ (which gives the power), will be the energy transferred per charge, times the charge that passes through a component per second, therefore it equals the energy transferred per second, which is the standard definition of power.

I hope this helps give at least some intuition of $P=IV$.